# svn error on merge where one branch must be ancestrally related to the other

Tags: svn, merge

I have two branches that were both created from trunk.

For branch 2.1, this branch was copied from trunk

For branch 2.2:

- First a branch folder V2.2 was created and added.
- Second a copy form trunk was performed into V2.2/code. So in fact the actual branch is the folder "code".
- subsequently, the "code" was svn moved back to the root folder V2.2. The end effect is that at this point, both branches (V2.1 & V2.2) appear identical.

Here is the issue, when we merge branch V2.1 to branch V2.2 we get the message: 
https://svn.mycorp.com/svn/star/branches/V2.1@49058 must be ancestrally related to https://svn.mycorp.com/svn/star/branches/V2.2@49040

Any idea how to merge this code back?  I tried to create a "code" folder back under the V2.2 branch and SVN move all the code back, but the same result when I attempt to merge V2.1 into the V2.2/code folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try the `--ignore-ancestry` option to `svn merge`.

This option ignores the merge info as well as the history, so you will need to manually select the revisions to merge. SVN will not figure out what changes to merge automatically.

Comment: I did try this and it came up with a error message that said a merge conflict had occurred and that I needed to resolve and then restart the merge.  I did not see any option in the tortiseSVN merge dialog that enabled me to resolve a conflict so I could restart. What is the benefit of performing an SVN merge and ignore ancestry vs. a file system merge using a toll like beyond compare.  Will the SVN merge and ignore ancestry automate any of the merge at that point so there is a clear benefit to using this option?

Comment: Um...double-click the conflict? Or is it a "tree conflict"? I still do not know how to fix those reliably. You may need to merge each subdirectory individually since it sounds like you assembled your "branch" piecemeal instead of making a real branch by copying the top-level directory.

Comment: when I attempt to ignore ancestry, tortiseSVN produces a dialog that says:
"Cannot merge automatically while ignoring mergeinfo"
How do i get around this?

Comment: @user2457075 You have to manually enter the revisions to merge. Automatic not an option with "ignore ancestry".